# JTable Custom Cell Editor for Dates (HH:mm format)

Tags: java, swing, validation, input, jtable

I am trying to create an input verifier for a jtable (Format HH:mm). I tried with KeyListeners and TableModelListener and decided finally that best solution would be a custom cell editor.

This is my Code so far:

```
public class DateEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    private JFormattedTextField textField;
    private static final DateFormat TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");


public DateEditor() {
    super( new JFormattedTextField() );
    textField = (JFormattedTextField) getComponent();


    textField.setFormatterFactory( new DefaultFormatterFactory( new DateFormatter(TIME_FORMAT) ) );
    textField.setFocusLostBehavior( JFormattedTextField.PERSIST );

    textField.getInputMap().put( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0 ), "check" );
    textField.getActionMap().put( "check", new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            if ( !textField.isEditValid() ) { //The text is invalid.
                if ( userSaysRevert() ) { //reverted
                    textField.postActionEvent(); //inform the editor
                }
            }
            else {
                try {              //The text is valid,
                    textField.commitEdit();     //so use it.
                    textField.postActionEvent(); //stop editing
                }
                catch ( java.text.ParseException exc ) {
                }
            }
        }
    } );
}

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent( JTable table,
                                              Object value, boolean isSelected,
                                              int row, int column ) {
    JFormattedTextField ftf = (JFormattedTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent( table, value, isSelected, row, column );
    ftf.setValue( value );
    return ftf;
}

public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    JFormattedTextField ftf = (JFormattedTextField) getComponent();
    Object o = ftf.getValue();
    System.out.println( "trying to parse date: " + o.getClass() );


    if ( o instanceof Date ) {


        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        System.out.println("Datum: " + simpleDateFormat.format(o));

        return simpleDateFormat.format(o);
    }
    else if ( o instanceof String ) {
        try {
            return TIME_FORMAT.parse( o.toString() );
        }
        catch ( ParseException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            return new Date();
        }
    }
    else {
        new RuntimeException( "What type: " + o.getClass() ).printStackTrace();
        return new Date();
    }
}

public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    JFormattedTextField ftf = (JFormattedTextField) getComponent();
    if ( ftf.isEditValid() ) {
        try {
            ftf.commitEdit();
        }
        catch ( java.text.ParseException exc ) {
        }

    }
    else { //text is invalid
        if ( !userSaysRevert() ) { //user wants to edit
            return false; //don't let the editor go away
        }
    }
    return super.stopCellEditing();
}

 protected boolean userSaysRevert() {
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    textField.selectAll();
    Object[] options = {"Ändern",
    "Abbrechen"};
    int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
            SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor( textField ),
            "Die Zeit muss im Format hh:mm eingegeben werden",
            "Falsches Eingabeformat",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,
            null,
            options,
            options[1] );

    if ( answer == 1 ) { //Revert!
         textField.setValue(textField.getValue());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

If input is 157:30 ftf.isEditValid() apparently becomes true and after editing the value is 13:30. But it should be false because 157:30 is not a valid time in HH:mm. Next time I click on the same cell it throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.InternationalFormatter.valueToString(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFormattedTextField$AbstractFormatter.install(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter.install(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.text.InternationalFormatter.install(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setFormatter(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(Unknown Source)
at DateEditor.getTableCellEditorComponent(DateEditor.java:57)
...
Code-Line 57: ftf.setValue( value );
```

What do I need to change in the code for correct verification ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks...fixed hanging Close bracket and made the question clearer.

Comment: Which type of objects contains the time column of your `JTable`?
`String` or `Date`? I guess it is `String`, because your 
`CellEditor.getTableCellEditorComponent` method currently can only
handle `Date` but not `String` values.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I did'nt specify this...      defaultTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(1, 7) {
          public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {             
               return editable;
          }
      };




  table = new JTable(defaultTableModel); I will try to Change that......

Comment: Even if you don't specify the type in the `getColumnClass()` method of `DefaultTableModel` you need to decide whether you put `String` (like `"08:00") or `Date` objects into it. My question was about that.

Comment: Yes...I am reading the inputs from a SQL database and store the results in an String Array. I should use an Array of Date Objects instead  then ?

Comment: It is up to you which type you prefer.
Just make sure `getTableCellEditorComponent` can receive that type
and `getCellEditorValue` will return that type consistently.

Comment: *"fixed hanging Close bracket and made the question clearer."* Let me know when you get around to posting that MCVE / SSCCE.